# How to play a video in loop while streaming RTSP in VLC using C# console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, rtsp, libvlc, vlc.dotnet

This is the code am using but not able to loop the video even after using :input-repeat=65535 in code. I need to play video in loop without doing any changes in vlc player.

```
string url = "https://demo.mp4";
int lastIndex = url.LastIndexOf("/");
string Path_1 = url.Substring(lastIndex + 1); //filename
string savePath = @"D:" + Path_1;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, savePath);
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"D:\Demo\" + Path_1);
var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

using (var mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
 {
   var mediaOptions = new[]
  {   ":sout=#gather:rtp{sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8022/test}",
      ":sout-keep",":network-caching = 150" ,":clock-jitter=0",
      ":clock-synchro=0" ,":input-repeat=65535"};                 
       mediaPlayer.SetMedia(file, mediaOptions);
       mediaPlayer.Play();
       Console.WriteLine("Streaming on rtsp://127.0.0.1:8022/test");
       Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
       Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: share full logs please

Comment: i have shared full one

Comment: no there are no **logs**